# Kubernetes Ingress - Ingress to ClusterIP service routing not working

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm currently testing Wordpress in Kuberntes (MicroK8s) on Ubuntu 22.10. Now I always have the problem that when I access "test.com", I am redirected to the IP address "192.168.210.200". My YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-creds
  namespace: wordpress
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
  MYSQL_USER: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql-service
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql-deployment
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: mysql
  minReadySeconds: 20
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: mysql-creds
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-pv-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-pv-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wordpress-creds
  namespace: wordpress
type: Opaque
data:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: d29yZHByZXNzLW15c3FsLXNlcnZpY2U= # wordpress-mysql-service
  WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ZXhhbXBsZWRhdGE=
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-frontend-service
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: https
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: wordpress
  name: wordpress-ingress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wordpress-frontend-service
            port:
              number: 80
            port:
              number: 443
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-frontend-deployment
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  minReadySeconds: 20
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: wordpress-creds
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-pv-volume
          mountPath: /var/www/html
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-pv-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wordpress-pv-claim
```

The file does not contain a Namespace, no PersistentVolumes and no PersistentVolumeClaims, since this is not relevant for solving the problem.

My subnet: 192.168.210.0/24

I enabled ingress with "microk8s enable ingress" and the nginx ingress controller pod is also running properly. Of course, I also made an entry for test.com in the hosts file (etc/hosts). The Wordpress and MySQL pods are both running as well.
What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your WordPress application is redirecting to the IP address instead of using the domain name. This is a common issue with WordPress when running behind a reverse proxy, like the Nginx ingress controller.

you can try adding the following lines to the wp-config.php file in your WordPress container:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://test.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://test.com');
```

This will tell WordPress to use test.com as the site URL instead of the IP address.

Additionally, you can check your Nginx ingress controller configuration to make sure it is properly forwarding traffic to your WordPress service. You should have an ingress resource that specifies the hostname and paths for your WordPress application, like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: wordpress-service
                port:
                  name: http
```

Make sure the host field matches the domain name you are using, and that the backend section points to your WordPress service.